# Need help in automation of capturing tcpdump on aks cluster please

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, tcpdump

Manual steps to capture tcpdump on aks worker nodes

```
kubectl debug node/<nodename> -it --image=mcr.microsoft.com/aks/fundamental/base-ubuntu:v0.0.11

chroot /host

tcpdump -i any -vvv -w /tmp/capture.dump &

kill -9 $!

kubectl cp nodename:/tmp/capture.dump /tmp
```

Now i am planning to automate it through jenkins. like i wanted to execute all the above commands remotely via shell script or any automation language. soon after running kubectl debug command next set of commands are not running & its stopping there. please help.#

Comment: What's the purpose of capturing the traffic?

Comment: Performance team  regularly perform load testing and they ask our team to capture tcpdump on few worker nodes to analyze.

Comment: You might want to use `-c <num-of-packets>` flag to gracefully end tcpdump after N packets are captured. Or use `timeout` to end it. Do not depend on `&` unless it's the last resort.